# Python - How do I append data if a specific word is printed?

Tags: python-3.x

So basically when my code runs, it searches "Condition, Sold Date and Sold Price." I'm trying to only search for "Pre-Owned" stuff on condition and print it if it IS "Pre-Owned."

```
for parts_item in parts_list:

        title = parts_item.find(class_='s-item__title--tag').next_element.next_element.text
        if title:
            data['Condition'].append(title) 
        else:
            data['Condition'].append('NA')

        sold_date = parts_item.find(class_='s-item__title--tag').text
        if sold_date:
            data['Sold Date'].append(sold_date)
        else:
            data['Sold Date'].append('NA')

        sold_price = parts_item.find(class_='s-item__price').text
        if sold_price:
            data['Sold Price'].append(sold_price)
        else:
            data['Sold Price'].append('NA')
```

Comment: Please provide runnable code that reproduces the problem, i.e. code with a `parts_list` in this case.

Comment: https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=2001+nissan+pathfinder+oem&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_oac=1&_ipg=200&rt=nc&LH_Complete=1&rt=nc&rt=nc&_pgn=        - Trying to get data from here.